# how to solve this limits

Tags: limits

How can i solve this,i didnt find similar exercise ,how the name is and if you could give me [this is the exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1T7T.jpg) . I may not understand much so try to answer it more analytic if you want or tell me how is this to read it because it isnt only limit.I find this exercise and i was trying to think how can i solve it.The exercise was telling  just to examinate this series.The easiest way is adviced .Thanks a lot

Comment: $-1+\ln 2$.................

Comment: i dont understand :(

Comment: Are you familiar with power series expansions? $ \ln (1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}x^n/n$ for $-1<x\leq 1.$

Comment: Awkward to do it without using the power-series expansion $\ln (1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}x^n/n$ for $-1<x\leq 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $\ln x=\int_1^x(1/t)dt$ for $x>0$ we show that (I). $0<\ln (1+x)<x$ for $x>0 $ and that (II). $\ln (1-y)<-y$ for  $0<y<1.$

Let $H(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n1/j.$ Let $S(n)=H(n)=\ln n$ and $T(n)=H(n)(-\ln (n+1)).$

From (I) and (II) we obtain $S(n+1)-S(n)<0<T(n+1)-T(n)$ so the sequence $(S(n))_n$ is decreasing and the sequence $(T(n))_n$ is increasing. And also, since $S(n)>T(n),$ each of these two sequences converges. That is $S(1)>S(2)>S(3)>...>T(3)>T(2)>T(1).$

BTW since $S(n)-T(n)=-\ln (1+1/n)$ converges to $0$ by (I), these two sequences have the same limit $\gamma=0.57712....,$ called Euler's Constant.

Let $V(n)= \sum_{j=1}^{2n}(-1)^{j+1}/j.$ Then $$V(n) =H(2n)-2H(n)= S(2n)-S(n)+\ln (2n)-\ln n=S(2n)-S(n)+\ln 2.$$ As $n\to \infty,$ both $S(2n)$ and $S(n)$ converge to the same value. So $$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{j+1}/j =\lim_{n\to \infty}V(n)=\ln 2. $$ Your exercise is to find $\lim_{n\to \infty}(-1+V(n)).$

Obvious, isn't it? LOL.

Comment: (-1^n+1/((n+1)+1) )  / (  -1^n) / (n+1) . Did this is right what i did?

Comment: I don't understand that.............